# How to customize stroke/path of chart lines in gooddata UI?

Tags: gooddata

I'm trying to accomplish this with GoodData UI react SDK:
[What its supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLqum.png)
https://monosnap.com/file/M4ZnX3ud3koAqCBNt5Pym6IHyZkznp

But my charts always have a thick stroke and filled data points:
[How it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4BVq.png)

https://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-ui/docs/line_chart_component.html
Shows no option of customizing the stroke/data points
Neither does
https://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-ui/docs/chart_config.html

Is there any way of doing it? I'm using
@gooddata/react-components 7.0.1

I've tried hacking it with CSS selectors /shrug

Comment: if you upload you images to imgur you can embed them in your question, you are much more likely to get an answer then

Comment: Hi Bruno, as I know there is no way how to define own graphical style of GoodData UI charts apart of custom color. If you need your own style you will need to create your own visualization component for rendering and use Execute component for only data fetching.

Comment: Damn, that's unlucky :/

Thanks for the answer though. Is there any plans to include it?

Comment: We have roadmap for around 10 months now and there is no such feature